# number cell format with text

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I want to export my data to excel using phpspreadsheet but my data is number in 12 character. So I need to display all the character (121212121212) instead of (1.21212E+11).

I have try the format using

```
PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT
```

and

```
PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER
```

It doesn't work.

This is my cell formatting code:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B')->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
```

This is my value insert code:

```
$sheet->setCellValue('A'.$i, $i-1);
        $sheet->setCellValue('B'.$i, $useric);
```

If I use the FORMAT_TEXT the result is this:

```
![result](https://i.imgur.com/6xxKDkv.png)
```

Answer (score 19):

when using PHPSpreadsheet, this is what I do.

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->getCell('A1')
            ->setValueExplicit(
                $someNumber,
                \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType::TYPE_STRING2
            );
```

If by any chance you using PHPExcel, maybe you can do something like this

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
            ->setCellValueExplicit('A1', $someNumber, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

Comment: Really surprised how difficult it was for me to find your answer on this one, with the naming conventions between the 2 and how bad google has gotten when searching for help on this stuff, it's like good luck dealing with debugging between the 2.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the [formatcode](https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/master/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Style/NumberFormat.html#method_setFormatCode) to @ (strings)

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B')->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('@');
```

Answer (score 4):

This works, in all the sheet

```
$spreadsheet ->getDefaultStyle()->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#');
```